# How to configure memory options for JDeveloper integrated Weblogic appc compiler?

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm working on a large Oracle ADF web project using JDeveloper. During development I run and test it in the JDeveloper Integrated Weblogic Server.
When I deploy the project to the server it builds the beans, JSPs etc and towards the end it outputs the following message in the Messages log:

```
[11:30:51 AM] Appc compilation begin
Compiling out of process...
D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Xverify:none -client -classpath D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\lib\tools.jar;D:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar -Dweblogic.jsp.diagnosticWithAbsolutePath=true -Dweblogic.classloader.noJarSigners=true weblogic.appc "@C:\Users\nb14588\AppData\Local\Temp\appcCommandList8852570431803898608.txt"
```

Very often, during this process (Appc compilation), the compiler has a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` (this appears in the Compiler log). Simultaneously, if I check the Windows task manager the `jawaw.exe` appc compilation process is consuming 30-40% CPU but apparently doing nothing. It seems deadlocked and only disappears if you kill it manually.

My question is where are those memory options (`-Xms128m -Xmx512m`) for this `jawaw.exe` process configured?

The files where they're **not** configured (as far as I can tell) are: `jdev.conf`, `ide.conf`, `commEnv.cmd`, `startWebLogic.cmd` and `setDomainEnv.cmd`. I don't know where else to look. I've grep'd everywhere for those memory options and can't find them anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As i discover that's not a "memory options" problem.
I found that APPC uses the %TMP% folder to store some temprary info.
And the folder %TEMP%\appc_libraries is locked, when such long compilations occurs.

So if you delete the %TMP%\appc_libraries, or change the %TMP% var value, compilation completes with normal time.

Comment: Even though this is an old post, would like to know where to change the value for `%TMP% var`?

Answer (score 0):

It will be inside **setDomainEnv.cmd** which will look something like the following:

```
set XMS_SUN_64BIT=256
set XMS_SUN_32BIT=256
set XMX_SUN_64BIT=512
set XMX_SUN_32BIT=512
set XMS_JROCKIT_64BIT=256
set XMS_JROCKIT_32BIT=256
set XMX_JROCKIT_64BIT=512
set XMX_JROCKIT_32BIT=512
```

Comment: Nope. I'd already tried changing those values. Makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Properties->click on compiler->out of process check box ->check it

After that rebuild your project

Now you will get rid of this problem